# Ajax event not triggered

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to trigger an AJAX event when both arrival and departure date are filled in, but unfortunately nothing is triggered. Without the if statement, the AJAX event is triggered.

Any thoughts?

reservations/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for [@hotel, @reservation] do |f|%>
  <div class="col col-sm-3">
    <%= f.input :arrival,
    as: :string,
    label:false,
    placeholder: "From",
    wrapper_html: { class: "inline_field_wrapper" },
    input_html:{ id: "start_date"} %>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-sm-3">
    <%= f.input :departure,
    as: :string,
    label:false,
    placeholder: "From",
    wrapper_html: { class: "inline_field_wrapper" },
    input_html:{ id: "end_date"} %>
  </div>

  <div class="col col-sm-4">
    <%= f.input :room_id, collection: @room_categories.order(:name), as: :grouped_select, group_method: :rooms,  label:false %>
  </div>

  <%= f.button :submit, "Search", class: "create-reservation-btn"%>
<% end %>
```

script for reservations/new.html.erb

```
<script>
const checkIn = document.querySelector('#start_date');
const checkOut = document.querySelector('#end_date');

// => if statement that doesn't work
if ((checkIn.value.length > 0) && (checkOut.value.length > 0)){

const checkInAndOut = [checkIn, checkOut];

checkInAndOut.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    checkAvailability();
  })
})
//}

  function checkAvailability(){

    $.ajax({
      url: "<%= rooms_availability_hotel_path(@hotel) %>" ,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: "POST",
      data: `arrival=${start_date.value}&departure=${end_date.value}`,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('succes')
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(response) {
        console.log('failure')
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  };
</script>
```

Comment: DO you realize the if statement runs only when the page loads? The logic needs to happen when you change the fields so move it there

Comment: Wow.... Thanks, you were right (and I cannot believe I missed this..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your length check

```
if ((checkIn.value.length > 0) && (checkOut.value.length > 0)){
```

into the listener function.

Because otherwise it is only called on page load and therefore is stopping the attachment of the listeners.

Comment: Wow.... Thanks, you were right (and I cannot believe I missed this..)